# How to Alphabetically retrieve members of a list?

Tags: grails-orm, gsp, grails

I have an organization class

```
class Organization {
hasMany = [member:Members]
}

class Members {
belongsTo = organization
}
```

I'm printing all the members using

```
<ol>
<g:each in="${organizationInstance?.members?}" var="m">
    <li><g:link controller="members" action="show" id="${m.id}">${m?.encodeAsHTML()}</g:link></li>
</g:each>
</ol>
```

I want to sort the printing of members so that it would print alphabetically. 
any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to change somehow your classes in order to have a name for members ! 
So let's assume that your classes are:

```
class Organization {
hasMany = [members:Member]
}

class Member {
belongsTo = organization
String name
}
```

Then you have two ways of sorting the members in alphabetical order.

**First method** :  you can retrieve all members and then sort them as shown below:

```
<g:each in="${organizationInstance?.members?.sort {it.name} }" var="m">
```

**Second Method** :  You retrieve members directly from GORM in alphabetical order

```
def members = Member.findAllByOrganization(organizationInstance, [sort: "name"])
```